# how to custom search using post method in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am the new in django. My problem is that I want to do search with URL like http://127.1.8000/shop/search/queryask pattern I don't want to use with query with question mark like ?q=abcd Can any body guide me that how to do this in url,view and django template files. Thanx

Comment: Please show us your code where do you want to implement this, it is possible. i have done it a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

You might do it via a couple of pretty arbitrary kwargs, although I wouldn't do this myself (I'd use GET and request.GET)

Anyway: **url**

```
path('mysearch/<int:pk>/<str:foo>/<str:bar>/',
         MySearchPostView.as_view(), name='whatever'),
```

You may or may not need pk to specify a particular entity to be involved in the search specified by foo and bar

**view:** whatever  CBV suits your purposes. It might, for example, be a `FormView` which validates that the user's `foo` and `bar` fields make sense in your context, and then does something. (You might well have no use for `pk` in this case)

```
class MySearchPostView(  FormView):

    #usual declarations template_name, form_class, etc. 

    def form_valid( self, form):

       foo = self.kwargs.get( 'foo')
       bar = self.kwargs.get( 'bar')

       # and stuff that was POSTed through the form

       baz = form.cleaned_data.get( 'baz')

       # now process these entities and decide whether they make sense together
       if (  conditions):       # if they are valid together
           return HttpResponseRedirect(
              reverse( 'myapp:some_other_view', kwargs={
                  ...
              }
            ))
        else:
            # add a non-field error
            form.add_error('', f"foo={foo} and bar={bar} are not valid together with baz={baz}" )
            return self.form_invalid( form)
```

If the invalid state indicated a JS programming error rather than a user input error, you could instead `return HttpResponseServerError( messsage)` (for Http response code 500)

**Template:** you will presumably be using some JS or similar to generate a POST to an URL with automatically generated `foo` and `bar` values. Display of the form would be absolutely standard. `{{form.as_p}}` will suffice for development purposes. The JS will be application-spoecific and outside the scope of this question, without knowing anything about the problem to be solved.

Comment: Thank you very much I try this and then let you know If I get any problem Thanx once again for the help